# Prevent jquery ui opening a second dialog box when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a leaflet map with 2 layers and when I'm clicking a button "save", it opens a dialog box with a form to send some informatons to my database.

When my first layer is selected and I'm clicking on my "save" button, it opens the dialog box corresponding to my first layer.

But then, when my second layer is selected and I'm clicking on my "save" button, it opens the dialog box corresponding to my second layer, but also the form I've opened just before for my first layer.

So, is it possible prevent the opening of this form ?
Because if I do a .dialog('close'), it on the form not corresponding, it works but we can see it opening and then closing, so that's not really good !

I have already tested .dialog("destroy"); and .remove(); but it removes my dialog boxes in the DOM and I can't open them other times after.

So, here is some code :

```html
//Code in the oneachfeature function from my layer1
 
$('#save').on('click',function(e){
var dialog1 = $("#dialog1").dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            show: {
                                  effect: "blind",
                                  duration: 500
                                },
                            hide: {
                                  effect: "blind",
                                  duration: 500
                                },
                            close: function(event, ui) {
                                    //$(this).dialog("destroy");
                                    //$(this).dialog("close");
                                    //$(this).remove();
                                },
                            height: 400,
                            width: 500,
                            modal: true,
                            position: {
                                my: "center center",
                                at: "center center",
                                of: "#map"
                                },
                            buttons: {
                            Valider: function() {
                                         
                                        // Ajax to send informations in the form
 
                                        }, // end of valider
                            Annuler: function() {
                                        dialog1.dialog("close");
                                        },
                                    }, // end of buttons                
                                }); // end of dialog
 
                            dialog1.dialog("open"); 

                            $("#dialog2").dialog('close');
 
                        });   // end of save
 
 
 
 
//Code in the oneachfeature function from my layer2
 
$('#save').on('click',function(e){
var dialog2 = $("#dialog2").dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            show: {
                                  effect: "blind",
                                  duration: 500
                                },
                            hide: {
                                  effect: "blind",
                                  duration: 500
                                },
                            close: function(event, ui) {
                                    //$(this).dialog("destroy");
                                    //$(this).dialog("close");
                                    //$(this).remove();
                                },
                            height: 400,
                            width: 500,
                            modal: true,
                            position: {
                                my: "center center",
                                at: "center center",
                                of: "#map"
                                },
                            buttons: {
                            Valider: function() {
                                         
                                        // Ajax to send informations in the form
 
                                        }, // end of valider
                            Annuler: function() {
                                        dialog2.dialog("close");
                                        },
                                    }, // end of buttons                
                                }); // end of dialog
 
                            dialog2.dialog("open"); 
                         
                            $("#dialog1").dialog('close');
 
                        });   // end of save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two save buttons, for each layer, seem to have the same id. Maybe there is a conflict when you install your "onclick" listeners ? So the behavior is not what you expect.
Try to set unique ids for these buttons

Comment: Yes, you're right, if I set unique ids it works but I want to have only one button to do it

Comment: Maybe you could try to "clean" the click event with the .off() Method : http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Also, I suggest you to name your functions that generate the dialog, and factorize it with parameters. Then with .on() and .off() and named functions readability should be better :)

Comment: So, I've tried adding  `$('#save').off('click',function(e){
    dialog1.dialog("open"); 
    });` for my first layer and the same with dialog2 for the second but it's still the same. Maybe I've done it wrong and you have an example ?

Comment: Hey, I did a JSFiddle to be more clear about the use of the off() function. https://jsfiddle.net/bzgyypfm/ Feel free to change the handler 'showDialog' by an anonymous function, like I said in the comments. Just an idea for the writing. Hope this will help !

Comment: For the use of the example, start by clicking on one link or the other, and then on the "Save" button. Then alternate with the two links and click on the "Save" button, the off() function kind of "resets" the click event.